# How do I use CONCAT+ in bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Under what circumstances do you use this formula?  I ran the query, I did not understand the results.  What is the purpose of using the formula?

Comment: give us better example!

Comment: For someone to be able to help you, give us details what you try to achieve, what have you tried, the query itself, what results do you get, and how they differ from your expectations.